# Retrieve the associated annotation from Uniprot

Tags: proteins, database, network

I have a dataset that I extracted using Cytoscape and STRINGAPI 
Hoz can I retreive the annotation of that network from uniprot  as it has more than 1k proteins . and doing it manually is not possible

Comment: Do you want anything specific from the annotation?

Comment: not really but it should contain the name the associated id , function maybe ...

Answer (score 1):

You can upload your list of accession numbers to the batch retrieval service for the UniProt Konwledgebase, http://www.uniprot.org/uploadlists

A video tutorial for this service is available at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kLdgjqWoMZc

Once you have retrieved your proteins, you can click on "Columns" to customize your output and add columns, e.g. for function annotation. See also http://www.uniprot.org/help/customize or http://insideuniprot.blogspot.ch/2015_03_01_archive.html 
Results can then be downloaded in tab-separated format.

If you have any additional questions, please don't hesitate to contact the UniProt helpdesk.